# $1-x=e^{-x+O(x^{2})}$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, computer-science, approximation

I'm struggling to understand a computer science article which uses the approximation, $1-x=e^{-x+O(x^{2})}$. I don't understand where they get this approximation from. To see what they might have done, I tried using:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+...$$

And integrating both sides to get

$$-\ln(1-x)=x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+...$$

I guess this must be equal to $x-O(x^{2})$, but I'm not sure how $\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+...$ can be negative. Is it that $-O(f(x))=O(f(x))$, so it doesn't matter what the sign is? I've only seen big O notation in the context of positive numbers.

From there I guess you would just multiply by $-1$ and exponentiate:

$$1-x=e^{-x+O(x^{2})}$$

Comment: We usually do not give sign to big-$O$. So $-O(x^2)=O(x^2)$. This is because the defintion of big-$O$ uses absolute values. Thus $-\ln(1-x)=x+O(x^2)$ and $\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$. Otherwise your argument is fine.

Comment: You can also simply use the Taylor expansion/definition of the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

We note that

$$
{1 \over 1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots 
$$
where it is assumed that $|x | < 1$.

We are considering only small values of $x$, otherwise the infinite series does not converge.

Integrating both sides (as RHS is a convergent series),
$$
- \ln| 1 - x | = x + {x^2 \over 2} + {x^3 \over 3} + \cdots
$$
which yields
$$
 (1 - x) = e^{- x - {x^2 \over 2} - {x^3 \over 3} + \cdots \}
$$

As $x \rightarrow 0$, $x^2$ term nominates the higher powers of $x$.

Hence, using the Big-O notation,
$$
1 - x = e^{-[x + O(x^2)]}
$$

I hope this answers your query!